# Problem writing a function that adds Columns for Transfer from and to club

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, columnsorting

I have a problem with a project of mine. I'm trying to make a clear overview of transfers in Football and I currently have this table:

| ClubID | PlayerID | FromDate | ToDate | TeamName | c_Person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2010-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | Club A | Player 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2012-02-01 | 2015-02-01 | Club B | Player 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2015-05-01 | 2018-02-01 | Club C | Player 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2010-01-01 | 2018-02-02 | Club A | Player 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2018-03-02 | 2020-02-01 | Club A | Player 2 |

However, I want to add columns FromClub & ToClub. If Player 1 first plays for Club A from 2010-01-01 to 2012-01-01 and transfers and plays for Club B from 2012-02-01 to 2015-02-01, I want the 'FromClub' and 'ToClub' illustrate the transfer.

I would like the table to look like this:

| ClubID | PlayerID | FromDate | ToDate | TeamName | c_Person | FromClub | ToClub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2010-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | Club A | Player1 | Nan | Nan |
| 2 | 1 | 2012-02-01 | 2015-02-01 | Club B | Player 1 | Club A | Club B |
| 3 | 1 | 2015-05-01 | 2018-02-01 | Club C | Player 1 | Club B | Club C |
| 1 | 2 | 2010-01-01 | 2018-02-02 | Club A | Player 2 | Nan | Nan |
| 1 | 2 | 2018-03-02 | 2020-02-01 | Club A | Player 2 | Nan | Nan |

I've been trying to write a function but am not able to solve it. Hopefully someone else can help me with this problem.

Here is the code to create the first Table:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'ClubID':[1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
                  'PlayerID':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                  'FromDate':["2010-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2015-05-01", "2010-01-01", "2018-03-02"],
                  'ToDate':["2012-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-02", "2020-02-01"],
                  'TeamName':["Club A", "Club B", "Club C",  "Club A", "Club A"],
                  'c_Person':["Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 2"]})

# convert the 'Date' columns to datetime format
df['FromDate']= pd.to_datetime(df['FromDate'])
df['ToDate']= pd.to_datetime(df['ToDate'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd like to explain the criteria as well to create these new two columns

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've updated the description. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for each row in your dataframe, include the information of previous team each Player had been before transfer:

```
df['PreviousTeam'] = df.groupby('PlayerID')['TeamName'].shift()

>>> df
   ClubID    FromDate  PlayerID TeamName      ToDate  c_Person PreviousTeam
0       1  2010-01-01         1   Club A  2012-01-01  Player 1          NaN
1       2  2012-02-01         1   Club B  2015-02-01  Player 1       Club A
2       3  2015-05-01         1   Club C  2018-02-01  Player 1       Club B
3       1  2010-01-01         2   Club A  2018-02-02  Player 2          NaN
4       1  2018-03-02         2   Club A  2020-02-01  Player 2       Club A
```

However if the Player gets transfered to same team, the previous team is same as current team (row #4). So apply below operation to fix that:

```
df['FromClub'] = df[df['PreviousTeam'] != df['TeamName']]['PreviousTeam']
```

Finally `ToClub` column can be obtained from `FromClub` by observing when the player was transferred:

```
df['ToClub'] = df[~df['FromClub'].isna()]['TeamName']

>>> df.drop('PreviousTeam', axis=1)
      ClubID    FromDate  PlayerID TeamName      ToDate  c_Person FromClub  ToClub
0       1  2010-01-01         1   Club A  2012-01-01  Player 1      NaN     NaN
1       2  2012-02-01         1   Club B  2015-02-01  Player 1   Club A  Club B
2       3  2015-05-01         1   Club C  2018-02-01  Player 1   Club B  Club C
3       1  2010-01-01         2   Club A  2018-02-02  Player 2      NaN     NaN
4       1  2018-03-02         2   Club A  2020-02-01  Player 2      NaN     NaN
```

So putting all inside a function, you can just call below with your dataframe and get the desired output:

```
def fill_club_details(df):
    df['PreviousTeam'] = df.groupby('PlayerID')['TeamName'].shift()
    df['FromClub'] = df[df['PreviousTeam'] != df['TeamName']]['PreviousTeam']
    df['ToClub'] = df[~df['FromClub'].isna()]['TeamName']
    return df.drop('PreviousTeam', axis=1)
```